# Is there quantitative theory of cutting with edge or blade

Tags: classical-mechanics, friction, material-science, continuum-mechanics

I wonder if there is some simple theory of what determine **efficiency ( speed, energy end force required )** of cutting by edge ( **blade , knife, sword** )

---

At least something phenomenological like in case of **friction** ( which I guess is very much related to cutting ) $F_F  = \mu F_\perp$ (where $F_F$ is friction force, $\mu$ is **friction coefficient** which is tabulated for specific materials, and $F_\perp$ is normal force - the force you push the surfaces into each other )

Particular problems which should be solved by this theory:

- Given a material ( i.e. some coefficients) and total force $F_{tot}$ asserted on the knife, what should be the optimal **tilt angle** $\alpha$ relative to surface normal to achieve **most efficient cutting**.  $\alpha$ determine decomposition of $F_{tot}$ into components perpendicular $F_\perp = \cos(\alpha) F_{tot}$ and parallel $F_\parallel = \sin(\alpha) F_{tot}$ to the surface.
- How it depends on [bevel angle](http://www.fooduniversity.com/foodu/food_c/basic_knife_skills/Knives/basic_knife_bevel_angle.htm) $\theta$ ( or possibly hardness of the tip and cut material )

To have some hint what such theory could be based on - in [this video (8:41)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G5_4uC3-Xu8)
is said that the blade actually works like **microscopic saw**. So, it would be probably quite straightforward to develop such theory having in mind a saw model with considering saw-tooth with particular **tooth tip angle** $\omega$ or some statistical distribution of such teeth

Comment: $\mu$ can not be tabulated, as it is also a properties of the surface topology, and the sword definition. Furthermore, I think to know from experience the optimal cutting angle also depends on the size of the object to be cut.